# Draggable popup with scrollbar issue in jQuery, Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, popup, scrollbar

I have created a draggable popup using jQuery that has a scrollbar. When I click the
scrollbar using Chrome, it moves with the mouse pointer and can not be released until I right click.

For the draggable popup, I am using jQuery, e.g.:

```
$("#id").draggable();
```

This works in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% what causes this, might be chrome's scrollbars rendering as html.

I'm afraid you'll need to initialize a draggable with the handle option specified.

```
$( "#id" ).draggable({ handle: '.yourhandleclass' });
```

It might also be possible to use the 'Cancel' option specified.
(Prevents dragging from starting on specified elements.)

Like this:

```
$( "#id" ).draggable({ cancel: '.replacethiswithchromescrollbarselector' });
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark your threads as answered when needed;-)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from :[Ticket #4441](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4441)

Code Sample:
`var drag = c.draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
            var t = event.target;
             if (event.pageX > t.offsetWidth + t.offsetLeft){
                return false;
            }
    }
});`